# Write the function `selfApp` in book *Types and Programming Languages* in scala

Tags: scala

[image]

Is it possible to write this function is Scala? Or any other language?

Comment: For those of us without a background in Lambda Calculus can you please translate the notation.

Comment: @davidrpugh Something like `selfApp(f: [X] X => X): [X] X => X = f(f)` (which isn't actually legal syntax).

Comment: "Is it possible to write this function is Scala? Or any other language?" – Yes, it is. In fact, you already posted an implementation in "any other language" in your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think it's possible in Scala without wrapping the function in an extra object. One way to do so would be:

```scala
type XtoX = {def apply[X](x: X): X }
def selfApp(f: XtoX): XtoX = f(f)
```

Now you can define an object with an apply method of the appropriate type like this:

```scala
object ID { def apply[X](x: X): X = x }
```

And call `selfApp` as `selfApp(ID)`, which will simply return the object it's given. However this will not work:

```scala
def id[X](x: X): X = x

selfApp(id)
```

Nor can you use an anonymous function `x => x`. This is because when passing methods or anonymous functions around, there's represented as `FunctionN` object and the `FunctionN` traits have monomorphic (i.e. non-generic) `apply` functions. So you need to explicitly create an object with a generic `apply` method yourself.

---

In Haskell you can do it without any wrapping by using the RankNTypes extension like this:

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes #-}
selfApp :: (forall x. x -> x) -> (forall x. x -> x)
selfApp f = f f
```

---

And of course in dynamically typed languages you can just write the function without worrying about types at all. For example in Python:

```py
def id(x): return x
def selfApp(f): return f(f)
print( selfApp(id)(42) ) # Just works - no extensions, no wrapping, no nothing
```

Comment: http://scalaz.github.io/scalaz/scalaz-2.9.0-1-6.0.1/doc.sxr/scalaz/Forall.scala.html#13208 so RankNTypes is implemented as objects in scala/java right?

Comment: @molikto Yes, or more precisely: All functions are implemented as objects in Scala, but higher-rank ones need to be represented as objects implementing custom traits (as opposed to `scala.Function1` etc.).